# Using 3rd party React Components without having .d.ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react-router v.4 and typescript v.2.2.

I'm trying to use a simple 3rd party component ([react-loading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading)) as a "component attribute" in react-router's Route. The 3rd party component doesn't have a @types .d.ts file. The react-router typings are in place.

I receive:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

Of course, putting a break-point in the render function, shows the Loading component NOT to be undefined, but the valid function needed.
Can I solve this quickly without writing a .d.ts file for the library?

LATER EDIT: (v.2)

I've tried following this [fine tutorial](https://templecoding.com/blog/2016/03/31/creating-typescript-typings-for-existing-react-components/) and after simplifying my code at maximum (**actually omitting react-router**), I came up with:

**index.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Loading from 'react-loading';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Loading type="balls" color="red"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and **typings/react-loading.d.ts**:

```
declare module 'react-loading' {

  import * as React from 'react';

  export interface LoadingProps {
    color?: string;
    delay?: number;
    height?: number;
    type?: string;
    width?: number;
  }

  export default class Loading extends React.Component<LoadingProps, any> {}
}
```

but I receive:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

Please note  that the typings file is in effect, as removing the **?** from the **height** attribute (for example)... gives the additional **new** error:

```
[at-loader] src\index.tsx:7:3 
    TS2324: Property 'height' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Loading> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & R...'.
```

Comment: could you provide some example code? You could try declaring some var as component and assign the untyped component to it. I mean if you know that it´s there, you can fake typescript to do so. it is just augmentation.

Comment: I'll try to make the smallest code that can reproduce the problem and have a second LATER EDIT

Comment: Make sure you don't have an `import ...` statement outside the `declare module 'react-loading' {...}` declaration. And put this declaration in a specific file.

Comment: I've updated my LATER EDIT and simplified the code at maximum. Even removed the routing altogether, now being sure it's not a react router problem but a pure TypeScript issue (or my lack of knowledge, of course)

Comment: removed the react-router TAG

Comment: I'm almost sure that you have wrong import. Test this one `import * as Loading from 'react-loading';`

Comment: @niba doing that results in: TS2604:JSX element type 'Loading' does not have any construct or call signatures. That's because the react-loading.js has this line declared: export default class Loading extends Component {

Comment: anyways... I ended up just using another Loading React Component from npm, which worked without any problems